# QFileSystemModel remove folder from Watcher

Tags: qt

I have a `QFilesystemModel` used in a `QTreeView`. Every time I remove a folder (e.g. through `shutils.rmtree()`) which is watched by the underlying `QFilesystemWatcher` I get a this warning

```
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /path/to/deleted/folder
```

In my mind this should be solved by removing the folder from `QFileSystemWatcher` before removing it with `QFileSystemWatcher.removePath()`. But this doesn't work as there [seem to be no way to get in touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281901/qt-how-to-get-qfilesystemwatcher-object-associated-with-qfilesystem) with the `QFileSystemWatcher` from a `QFileSystemModel` (I searched for a solution without luck).

So is there any other way I can tell the `QFileSystemModel` to stop watching the folder?

PS: I know I could use `QFileSystemModel.remove()` or `.rmdir()` which would handle this automaticaly. But that's not an option for me. I need to remove the folder from outside the `QFileSystemModel`.

I'm using Qt4 with Python3 on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Firstly, `QFileSystemModel` and `QFileSystemWatcher` are two different classes. They are not related in any way what-so-ever. `QFileSystemModel` does not do the watching, you should add the file watcher yourself.</s>

By the way, do realize the `QFileSystemModel::remove` just deletes the file. You'll still get the error.

The `QFileSystemWatcher` is buried very deep beneath the code for `QFileSystemModel` which is why you cannot access it.

#### Edit:

However, there is a simple way as to how you can avoid the warning. Here is a code snippet. We are assuming that there is a folder called /tmp/trial with some files in it. This is the folder being viewed, and is deleted externally.

```
### == Code that creates a warning == ###

# Initial state
fsm = QFileSystemModel()
lv = QListView()
lv.setRootIndex( fsm.setRootPath( "/tmp/trial" ) )

# External deletion of "/tmp/trial", leads to this error
shutils.rmtree( "/tmp/trial" )
# Error
   QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: file or directory not found
   QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /tmp/trial


### == Suggested edit == ###

# Initial state
fsm = QFileSystemModel()
lv = QListView()
lv.setRootIndex( fsm.setRootPath( "/tmp/trial" ) )

# Just before deleting
lv.setRootIndex( fsm.setRootPath( "/tmp" ) )

# External deletion of "/tmp/trial", gives no error
# This even look very neat for the user.
shutils.rmtree( "/tmp/trial" )
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have skipped the proxy model and used a list view, but the procedure be the same in your case with proxy model and tree view.

Comment: Thanks. `QFileSystemModel` creates a new `QFileSystemWatcher` internal, doesn't it? I did not add a watcher yet but obviously there is one. So where would it come from? Or how could I connect a new `QFileSystemWatcher` to the model? I don't see any function in neither of both classes which would do this. The `QFileSystemModel` is used through a `QSortFilterProxyModel` inside a `QTreeView`.

Comment: Yes you are very right, I was looking through the sources. However, the `QFileSystemWatcher` used internally in buried deep beneath the code and we probably need an heavy duty excavator to get to it. :D

Comment: I'll shortly edit my answer above. But here is what you can do. If you are using `QFileSystemModel` to show files and folders, I think what you could do, first go to the parent directory, then delete the folder you were previously displaying. That will get rid of the error from the watcher.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer!